# Vulkan Raytracing KHR no ray intersection

Tags: c++, shader, vulkan, raytracing

I have been trying to get vulkan raytracing to work using VK_KHR_ray_tracing_pipeline.
Everything is setup and I can render frames (currently ray direction at each pixel).
It seems like TLAS and BLAS are valid when I look at the application through Nsight:
[Acceleration Structure in Nsight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZdIX.png)

Also, both TLAS and BLAS buffers are not empty and the vertex data is correct.

However I can't seem to get any ray intersection, judging by the hit shader never being called:
[Nsight shader profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zsro.png)

Ray generation and miss shaders work as intended.

The shader binding table should also be correct. All shaders show up in Nsight including correct indices on the stages and assignment in the groups:
[Shader Stages and Groups in Nsight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33gqp.png)

I must have triple-checked everything from the vulkan instance over acceleration structure build to shader binding table.
After over a week of troubleshooting I was not able to fix it.

What could be the cause of this?

PS: Validation layers are enabled and seemingly working. I don't get any errors apart from an occasional device lost when building the BLAS, which may be indicative of an error on my side but I can't seem to find it.

I ensured that BLAS and TLAS builds are properly synchronized by adding pipeline barriers.
I made sure that all necessary extensions are enabled.
I also enabled verbose and info validation messages as well as best practice and synchronization validation features to see if some message would lead me to the issue.
I have tried different layouts of the shader binding table. (All shaders show up and make sense in Nsight)
I have tried different geometries.
I have tried changing raygen, closest hit and miss shaders.
None of these attempts caused behaviour which I didn't expect except for the hit shader not being called and the BLAS build sometimes failing.

BLAS build code:

```cpp
void Geometry::setup_build_info()
{
    VkDeviceAddress vertexBufferAddress                    = vkf::getBufferDeviceAddress(m_device->get(), m_mesh.positions.GetBuffer());
    VkDeviceAddress indexBufferAddress                     = vkf::getBufferDeviceAddress(m_device->get(), m_mesh.indices.GetBuffer());

    m_geometry                                             = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_GEOMETRY_KHR };
    m_geometry.flags                                       = VK_GEOMETRY_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
    m_geometry.geometryType                                = VK_GEOMETRY_TYPE_TRIANGLES_KHR;
    m_geometry.geometry.triangles                          = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_GEOMETRY_TRIANGLES_DATA_KHR };
    m_geometry.geometry.triangles.vertexFormat             = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
    m_geometry.geometry.triangles.vertexData.deviceAddress = vertexBufferAddress;
    m_geometry.geometry.triangles.vertexStride             = 3 * sizeof(float);
    m_geometry.geometry.triangles.indexType                = VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32;
    m_geometry.geometry.triangles.indexData.deviceAddress  = indexBufferAddress;
    m_geometry.geometry.triangles.maxVertex                = uint32_t(m_mesh.numVertices);
    m_geometry.geometry.triangles.transformData            = { 0 };    // No transform

    m_build_info                                           = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_GEOMETRY_INFO_KHR };
    m_build_info.type                                      = VK_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BOTTOM_LEVEL_KHR;
    m_build_info.mode                                      = VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_MODE_BUILD_KHR;
    m_build_info.flags = VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_PREFER_FAST_TRACE_BIT_KHR /* | VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_ALLOW_UPDATE_BIT_KHR*/;
    m_build_info.geometryCount = 1;
    m_build_info.pGeometries   = &m_geometry;
}

void Geometry::create()
{
    setup_build_info();

    VkAccelerationStructureBuildRangeInfoKHR rangeInfo;
    rangeInfo.firstVertex     = 0;
    rangeInfo.primitiveCount  = uint32_t(m_mesh.numFaces);
    rangeInfo.primitiveOffset = 0;
    rangeInfo.transformOffset = 0;

    VkAccelerationStructureBuildSizesInfoKHR sizeInfo{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_SIZES_INFO_KHR };
    vkf::vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR(m_device->get(),
                                                 VK_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_TYPE_DEVICE_KHR,
                                                 &m_build_info,
                                                 &m_mesh.numFaces,
                                                 &sizeInfo);

    // Allocate a buffer for the acceleration structure.
    VkResult error = m_blas_buffer.Create(
      sizeInfo.accelerationStructureSize,
      VK_BUFFER_USAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_STORAGE_BIT_KHR | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_SHADER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT,
      VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT,
      VK_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT);
    vkf::CHECKM(error, "blas.buffer.create");

    // Create an empty acceleration structure object.
    VkAccelerationStructureCreateInfoKHR createInfo{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_CREATE_INFO_KHR };
    createInfo.type   = m_build_info.type;
    createInfo.size   = sizeInfo.accelerationStructureSize;
    createInfo.buffer = m_blas_buffer.GetBuffer();
    vkf::CHECKM(vkf::vkCreateAccelerationStructureKHR(m_device->get(), &createInfo, nullptr, &m_blas), "blas.create");

    m_build_info.dstAccelerationStructure = m_blas;

    m_update_scratch_size                 = sizeInfo.updateScratchSize;

    vulkanhelpers::Buffer scratchBuffer;
    scratchBuffer.Create(sizeInfo.buildScratchSize,
                         VK_BUFFER_USAGE_SHADER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT,
                         0,
                         VK_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT);
    m_build_info.scratchData.deviceAddress = vkf::getBufferDeviceAddress(m_device->get(), scratchBuffer.GetBuffer());

    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo commandBufferAllocateInfo;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.sType              = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.pNext              = nullptr;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.commandPool        = *m_cmd_pool;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.level              = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer                = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    vkf::CHECKM(vkAllocateCommandBuffers(m_device->get(), &commandBufferAllocateInfo, &commandBuffer), "vkAllocateCommandBuffers");

    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo;
    beginInfo.sType            = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beginInfo.pNext            = nullptr;
    beginInfo.flags            = 0;
    beginInfo.pInheritanceInfo = nullptr;

    VkMemoryBarrier memoryBarrier;
    memoryBarrier.sType                                  = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    memoryBarrier.pNext                                  = nullptr;
    memoryBarrier.srcAccessMask                          = VK_ACCESS_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_WRITE_BIT_KHR;
    memoryBarrier.dstAccessMask                          = VK_ACCESS_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_READ_BIT_KHR;

    error                                                = vkQueueWaitIdle(m_device->m_graphics_queue);
    error                                                = vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

    VkAccelerationStructureBuildRangeInfoKHR* pRangeInfo = &rangeInfo;
    vkf::vkCmdBuildAccelerationStructuresKHR(commandBuffer,    // The command buffer to record the command
                                             1,                // Number of acceleration structures to build
                                             &m_build_info,    // Array of ...BuildGeometryInfoKHR objects
                                             &pRangeInfo);     // Array of ...RangeInfoKHR pointers

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer,
                         VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_BIT_KHR,
                         VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_BIT_KHR,
                         0,
                         1,
                         &memoryBarrier,
                         0,
                         nullptr,
                         0,
                         nullptr);

    error = vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo;
    submitInfo.sType                = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submitInfo.pNext                = nullptr;
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount   = 0;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores      = nullptr;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask    = nullptr;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount   = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers      = &commandBuffer;
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 0;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores    = nullptr;

    error                           = vkQueueSubmit(m_device->m_graphics_queue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    error                           = vkQueueWaitIdle(m_device->m_graphics_queue);
    vkFreeCommandBuffers(m_device->get(), *m_cmd_pool, 1, &commandBuffer);
}
```

TLAS build code:

```cpp
void TopLevelAccelerationStructure::create()
{
    using VkASInstance = VkAccelerationStructureInstanceKHR;

    VkAccelerationStructureDeviceAddressInfoKHR addressInfo{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_INFO_KHR };
    VkDeviceAddress                             blas_address;

    float                                       transform[12] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    //
                                                                  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    //
                                                                  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

    std::vector<VkASInstance>                   instances(m_geometries.size());

    VkASInstance*                               instance;

    int                                         i = 0;

    for (auto const& geom : m_geometries)
    {
        addressInfo.accelerationStructure = geom.second.m_blas;
        blas_address                      = vkf::vkGetAccelerationStructureDeviceAddressKHR(m_device->get(), &addressInfo);

        instance                          = &instances[i];

        std::memcpy(instance->transform.matrix, transform, sizeof(transform));
        instance->instanceCustomIndex = geom.first;
        instance->mask                = 0xFF;    // Binary 11111111 meaning a mask which alway enables ray intersection with this structure
        instance->instanceShaderBindingTableRecordOffset = 0;
        instance->flags = 0 | VK_GEOMETRY_INSTANCE_TRIANGLE_FACING_CULL_DISABLE_BIT_KHR /* | VK_GEOMETRY_INSTANCE_FORCE_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR*/;
        instance->accelerationStructureReference = blas_address;

        ++i;
    }

    m_instances_buffer = vulkanhelpers::Buffer();
    VkResult error =
      m_instances_buffer.Create(instances.size() * sizeof(VkASInstance),
                                VK_BUFFER_USAGE_SHADER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_INPUT_READ_ONLY_BIT_KHR,
                                VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT,
                                VK_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT);
    CHECK_VK_ERROR(error, "instances_buffer.create");

    if (!m_instances_buffer.UploadData(instances.data(), m_instances_buffer.GetSize()))
    {
        assert(false && "Failed to upload instances buffer");
    }

    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo commandBufferAllocateInfo;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.sType              = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.pNext              = nullptr;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.commandPool        = *m_cmd_pool;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.level              = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    commandBufferAllocateInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer                = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    vkf::CHECKM(vkAllocateCommandBuffers(m_device->get(), &commandBufferAllocateInfo, &commandBuffer), "vkAllocateCommandBuffers");

    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo;
    beginInfo.sType            = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beginInfo.pNext            = nullptr;
    beginInfo.flags            = 0;
    beginInfo.pInheritanceInfo = nullptr;

    // Add a memory barrier to ensure that createBuffer's upload command
    // finishes before starting the TLAS build.
    VkMemoryBarrier barrier{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_BARRIER };
    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_WRITE_BIT_KHR;

    vkQueueWaitIdle(m_device->m_graphics_queue);
    vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer,
                         VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
                         VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_BIT_KHR,
                         0,
                         1,
                         &barrier,
                         0,
                         nullptr,
                         0,
                         nullptr);

    // vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

    VkAccelerationStructureBuildRangeInfoKHR rangeInfo;
    rangeInfo.primitiveOffset = 0;
    rangeInfo.primitiveCount  = instances.size();    // Number of instances
    rangeInfo.firstVertex     = 0;
    rangeInfo.transformOffset = 0;

    VkAccelerationStructureGeometryInstancesDataKHR instancesVk{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_GEOMETRY_INSTANCES_DATA_KHR };
    instancesVk.arrayOfPointers    = VK_FALSE;
    instancesVk.data.deviceAddress = vkf::getBufferDeviceAddress(m_device->get(), m_instances_buffer.GetBuffer());

    // Like creating the BLAS, point to the geometry (in this case, the
    // instances) in a polymorphic object.
    VkAccelerationStructureGeometryKHR geometry{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_GEOMETRY_KHR };
    geometry.geometryType       = VK_GEOMETRY_TYPE_INSTANCES_KHR;
    geometry.geometry.instances = instancesVk;

    // Create the build info: in this case, pointing to only one
    // geometry object.
    VkAccelerationStructureBuildGeometryInfoKHR buildInfo{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_GEOMETRY_INFO_KHR };
    buildInfo.flags         = VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_PREFER_FAST_TRACE_BIT_KHR /*| VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_ALLOW_UPDATE_BIT_KHR*/;
    buildInfo.geometryCount = 1;
    buildInfo.pGeometries   = &geometry;
    buildInfo.mode = VK_BUILD_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_MODE_BUILD_KHR;    // TODO change to update mode depending on parameter to facilitate update
    buildInfo.type = VK_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_TYPE_TOP_LEVEL_KHR;

    // Query the worst-case AS size and scratch space size based on
    // the number of instances.
    VkAccelerationStructureBuildSizesInfoKHR sizeInfo{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_SIZES_INFO_KHR };
    vkf::vkGetAccelerationStructureBuildSizesKHR(m_device->get(),
                                                 VK_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_TYPE_DEVICE_KHR,
                                                 &buildInfo,
                                                 &rangeInfo.primitiveCount,
                                                 &sizeInfo);

    // Allocate a buffer for the acceleration structure.
    m_tlas_buffer.Create(
      sizeInfo.accelerationStructureSize,
      VK_BUFFER_USAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_STORAGE_BIT_KHR | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_SHADER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT /* | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT*/,
      VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT,
      VK_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT);


    // byte*                             test = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(m_tlas_buffer.Map());

    // Create the acceleration structure object.
    // (Data has not yet been set.)
    VkAccelerationStructureCreateInfoKHR createInfo{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_CREATE_INFO_KHR };
    createInfo.type   = buildInfo.type;
    createInfo.size   = sizeInfo.accelerationStructureSize;
    createInfo.buffer = m_tlas_buffer.GetBuffer();

    error             = vkf::vkCreateAccelerationStructureKHR(m_device->get(), &createInfo, nullptr, &m_tlas);
    CHECK_VK_ERROR(error, "tlas.create");

    buildInfo.dstAccelerationStructure   = m_tlas;

    // Allocate the scratch buffer holding temporary build data.
    vulkanhelpers::Buffer scratch_buffer = vulkanhelpers::Buffer();

    scratch_buffer.Create(sizeInfo.buildScratchSize,
                          VK_BUFFER_USAGE_SHADER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT,
                          0,
                          VK_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BIT);

    buildInfo.scratchData.deviceAddress                  = vkf::getBufferDeviceAddress(m_device->get(), scratch_buffer.GetBuffer());

    // vkQueueWaitIdle(m_device->m_graphics_queue);
    // vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

    // Create a one-element array of pointers to range info objects.
    VkAccelerationStructureBuildRangeInfoKHR* pRangeInfo = &rangeInfo;
    // Build the TLAS.
    vkf::vkCmdBuildAccelerationStructuresKHR(commandBuffer, 1, &buildInfo, &pRangeInfo);

    VkMemoryBarrier memoryBarrier;
    memoryBarrier.sType         = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    memoryBarrier.pNext         = nullptr;
    // memoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_WRITE_BIT_KHR | VK_ACCESS_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_READ_BIT_KHR;
    memoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_WRITE_BIT_KHR;    // testing
    // memoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_WRITE_BIT_KHR | VK_ACCESS_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_READ_BIT_KHR;
    memoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_READ_BIT_KHR;    // testing

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer,
                         VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_BIT_KHR,
                         VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_BUILD_BIT_KHR,
                         0,
                         1,
                         &memoryBarrier,
                         0,
                         0,
                         0,
                         0);

    vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo;
    submitInfo.sType                = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submitInfo.pNext                = nullptr;
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount   = 0;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores      = nullptr;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask    = nullptr;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount   = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers      = &commandBuffer;
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 0;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores    = nullptr;

    error                           = vkQueueSubmit(m_device->m_graphics_queue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    error                           = vkQueueWaitIdle(m_device->m_graphics_queue);
    vkFreeCommandBuffers(m_device->get(), *m_cmd_pool, 1, &commandBuffer);
}
```

Code for recording command buffers for rendering:

```
void VulkanSession::fill_command_buffer(VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer, const size_t imageIndex)
{
    vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_RAY_TRACING_KHR, m_pipeline);

    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer,
                            VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_RAY_TRACING_KHR,
                            m_rt_pipeline_layout,
                            0,
                            static_cast<uint32_t>(m_descr_sets.size()),
                            m_descr_sets.data(),
                            0,
                            0);

    vkCmdPushConstants(commandBuffer, m_rt_pipeline_layout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL, 0, sizeof(PushConstantRay), &m_push_constant);


    VkDeviceAddress sbt_buffer_adress = vkf::getBufferDeviceAddress(m_device.get(), m_sbt_helper.GetSBTBuffer());

    m_rayGenRegion                    = {};
    m_rayGenRegion.deviceAddress      = sbt_buffer_adress + m_sbt_helper.GetRaygenOffset();
    m_rayGenRegion.stride             = m_sbt_helper.GetRaygenSize();
    m_rayGenRegion.size               = m_sbt_helper.GetRaygenSize();

    m_missRegion                      = {};
    m_missRegion.deviceAddress        = sbt_buffer_adress + m_sbt_helper.GetMissGroupsOffset();
    // m_missRegion.deviceAddress         = sbt_buffer_adress + m_sbt_helper.GetRaygenSize();
    m_missRegion.stride               = m_sbt_helper.GetGroupsStride();
    m_missRegion.size                 = m_sbt_helper.GetMissGroupsSize();

    m_hitRegion                       = {};
    m_hitRegion.deviceAddress         = sbt_buffer_adress + m_sbt_helper.GetHitGroupsOffset();
    // m_hitRegion.deviceAddress          = sbt_buffer_adress + m_sbt_helper.GetRaygenSize() + m_sbt_helper.GetMissGroupsSize();
    m_hitRegion.stride                = m_sbt_helper.GetGroupsStride();
    m_hitRegion.size                  = m_sbt_helper.GetHitGroupsSize();

    m_callableRegion                  = {};

    vkf::vkCmdTraceRaysKHR(commandBuffer,
                           &m_rayGenRegion,
                           &m_missRegion,
                           &m_hitRegion,
                           &m_callableRegion,
                           m_window->size().width(),
                           m_window->size().height(),
                           1);
}

void VulkanSession::fill_command_buffers()
{
    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo commandBufferBeginInfo;
    commandBufferBeginInfo.sType             = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    commandBufferBeginInfo.pNext             = nullptr;
    commandBufferBeginInfo.flags             = 0;
    commandBufferBeginInfo.pInheritanceInfo  = nullptr;

    VkImageSubresourceRange subresourceRange = { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

    vkQueueWaitIdle(m_device.m_graphics_queue);    // TODO: needed ?

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_render_cmd_buffers.size(); i++)
    {
        const VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = m_render_cmd_buffers[i];

        VkResult              error         = vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &commandBufferBeginInfo);
        CHECK_VK_ERROR(error, "vkBeginCommandBuffer");

        vulkanhelpers::ImageBarrier(commandBuffer,
                                    m_offscreen_image.GetImage(),
                                    subresourceRange,
                                    0,
                                    VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT,
                                    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
                                    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL);

        this->fill_command_buffer(commandBuffer, i);    // user draw code

        vulkanhelpers::ImageBarrier(commandBuffer,
                                    m_swap_chain.m_images[i],
                                    subresourceRange,
                                    0,
                                    VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
                                    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
                                    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL);

        vulkanhelpers::ImageBarrier(commandBuffer,
                                    m_offscreen_image.GetImage(),
                                    subresourceRange,
                                    VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT,
                                    VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT,
                                    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL,
                                    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL);

        VkImageCopy copyRegion;
        copyRegion.srcSubresource = { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 0, 1 };
        copyRegion.srcOffset      = { 0, 0, 0 };
        copyRegion.dstSubresource = { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 0, 1 };
        copyRegion.dstOffset      = { 0, 0, 0 };
        copyRegion.extent         = { m_swap_chain.m_extent.width, m_swap_chain.m_extent.height, 1 };
        vkCmdCopyImage(commandBuffer,
                       m_offscreen_image.GetImage(),
                       VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
                       m_swap_chain.m_images[i],
                       VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
                       1,
                       &copyRegion);

        vulkanhelpers::ImageBarrier(commandBuffer,
                                    m_swap_chain.m_images[i],
                                    subresourceRange,
                                    VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
                                    0,
                                    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
                                    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR);

        error = vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);
        CHECK_VK_ERROR(error, "vkEndCommandBuffer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Been looking at similar stuff myself recently. Ensure `maxVertex` is correct, it should be the max index, not the count (probably not the issue here). It would help if you show how you record your TraceRays command, too.

Comment: @TylerKropp thank you for your comment. I have tried both count and last index for the `maxVertex` without change, but I have changed it back to `numVertices - 1`. I have also added the code I use for recording the command buffers to the question.